# How to dismiss Detail view when using a split view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am wanting to dismiss the view of my DetailViewController when a cancel button is pressed.

When I simply have two view controllers, say a Master and Detail, I can dismiss the detail view as follows:

```
@IBAction func pressedCancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Dismiss the view
    if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {   
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

This does not work when using a split view controller that has a detail and master view under it. When in portrait view on an iPhone for example, I am simply wanting the detail view to be dismissed when clicking the cancel button.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `UINavigationController` to the detail of a `UISplitViewController` using `showDetailViewController` in the context of a `.compact` horizontal size class. It pushes the `UINavigationController` on the master's `UINavigationController`, so when you want to dismiss the detail `UINavigationController` you need to message the master `UINavigationController`. Something like the following should work.

```
@IBAction func pressedCancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let navC = navigationController?.navigationController
    navC?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Here we check if the navigation controller has a navigation controller and ask it to pop its topmost view controller.

Comment: Awesome, yes it did work. Just to clarify my understanding, when the app starts in portrait mode, the `UISplitViewController` is the first item on the "view" stack. Because of how `AppDelegate` is set up, the master view's `UINavigationController` is the next to be added to the stack. Now when I transition to the `DetailViewController`, the detail view's `UINavigationController` is added to the stack, representing the `DetailViewController`. Thus, in order to ask the detail `UINavigationController` to pop, we must go one level above it to ask, since possibly it cannot pop itself?

Comment: Yes, if you only call pop on `navigationController` (i.e. the detail navigation controller) it's already at the `rootViewController` a so it does nothing. But this navigation controller is in the navigation stack of the master navigation controller so when you ask `navigationController?.navigationController` to pop the topmost view controller it pops the detail navigation controller. This is kind of a weird quirk of `UISplitViewController`.